# Fourier transform of the crystal lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

I am trying to show that the Fourier transform (not the Fourier series) of a crystal lattice can only be non-zero at the points of the reciprocal lattice. For this I have tried to describe the lattice with the help of the Shah function:

$$\rho(\vec r) = Ш(\vec r, \vec a_1) \ast Ш(\vec r, \vec a_2) \ast Ш(\vec r, \vec a_3) \ast B(\vec r)$$

With B a function that describes the basis.
However, there is the problem here that I do not know any convention for a multi-dimensional Shah function and accordingly I cannot calculate the Fourier transform. In the above equation I have assumed something like this:

$$Ш(\vec r, \vec a) := \sum \limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(\vec r - n \vec a)$$

Hence my question, how to determine the Fourier transform for a multidimensional function with periods

$$\vec R = n_1 \vec a_1 + n_2 \vec a_2 + n_3 \vec a_3 \qquad n_1, n_2, n_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Well, you can always write the multi-dimensional Dirac comb explicitly as a triple sum, and go from there.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I have tried something in this direction, but there is the problem that the single delta terms are coupled and you cannot divide the sum. One would then have to assume that the a_i have only one component in order to obtain the one-dimensional Shah function, but then one generally no longer obtains a rectangular coordinate system.